# Allocating array in unmanaged C++ code after passing IntPtr pointer in C#, Marshaling Types

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, unmanaged, managed

I'm trying to implement some project involving marshaling arrays between managed C# and unmanaged C++ codes. I'm facing a problem and none of the solutions found by me on web seem to work. I would greatly appreciate any comments on this regard.

I'm not presenting the full code, but very much simplified part showing the issue. Although it looks like a large piece - it is very simple - just conceptual. Just wanted to give as much full picture as possible.

**C++ part:**

*Object.h*

```
class cObject
{
public:
    //...constructor, destructor...
    int Method_Known_Size(double* array, int size);
    int Method_Unknown_Size(double* array);
    ...
    void FreeArray(double* p);
}
```

*Object.cpp*

```
int Method_Known_Size(double* array, int size)
{
    //modify array somehow..
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) array[i] = i;

}

int method_Unknown_Size(double* array)
{
    int size = 9;
    array = new double[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) array[i] = i;
}
```

(skipping Caller.h)
*Caller.cpp*

```
//...callers for constructor, destructor, for releasing unmanaged memory...
extern "C" int __stdcall Run_Known_Size(cObject* pObject, double* array, int size)
{
     return cObject->Method_Known_Size(array, size);
}

extern "C" int __stdcall Run_Unknown_Size(cObject* pObject, double* array)
{
     return cObject->Method_Unknown_Size(array);
}

extern "C" void __stdcall Release(cObject* cObject, double* array)
{
     if(cObject != NULL) cObject->FreeArray(array);
}
```

So, basically `Run_Known_Size` method just modifies already allocated by C# memory, and `Run_Unknown_Size` creates the array and modifies it.

**C# part**

```
public class DllWrapper: IDisposable
{       
    /* Creating an object, disposing,...
    [DllImport("cObject.dll")]
    CreateObject();...DisposeObject(IntPtr pObject);
    ...CallFreeArray(IntPtr pArray);*/

    [DllImport("cObject.dll")]
    private static extern int CallRun_Known_Size(IntPtr pObject, 
           [Out] double [] arr_allocated, int size);

    [DllImport("cObject.dll")]
    private static extern int CallRun_Unknown_Size(IntPtr pObject, 
           [Out] IntPtr arr_not_allocated);                         

    private IntPtr m_pNativeObject;

    public DllWrapper()
    {
        this.m_pNativeObject = CreateObject();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool bDisposing)
    {
        if (this.m_pNativeObject != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            DisposeObject(this.m_pNativeObject);
            this.m_pNativeObject = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        if (bDisposing)
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    ~DllWrapper()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void ReleaseUnmanAraray(IntPtr pArr)
    {
        CallFreeArray(pArr);
    }

    public int Run_Known_Size(double[] arr_allocated, int size)
    {
        return CallRun_Known_Size(this.m_pNativeObject, arr_allocated, size);
    }

    public int Run_Unknown_Size(IntPtr arr_not_allocated)
    {
        return CallRun_Known_Size(this.m_pNativeObject, arr_not_allocated);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] alloc_arr = new double[] { 1, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9,1 };
    int size = 9;            


    double[] Arr_for_Copy = new double[size];

    IntPtr pArr = new IntPtr();

    DllWrapper wrapper = new DllWrapper();

    int res1 = Run_Known_Size(alloc_arr, size);
    int res2 = Run_Unknown_size(pArr);

    if (pArr != IntPtr.Zero) // pArr IS ZERO ALWAYS!!!!!!
    {
        Marshal.Copy(pArr, Arr_for_Copy, 0, size);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pointer was zero again");
    }

    wrapper.ReleaseUnmanAraray(pScores);
    wrapper.Dispose();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Everything works just fine with arrays allocated in C# - they come modified from C++ with no errors. But in case when I don't know the size of an array, therefore could not preallocate arrays, the only solution that I found is to pass [Out] IntPtr and let C++ manage the memory, allocate and modify array. Then returned IntPtr can be marshaled to C#'s double[] array because we already know the size (for simplification I just put number 4 as the size, but I pass int* size to determine the size).

All my trials end up with zero pointer (with no error) after passing IntPtr and creating array in C++ based on this pointer.

I've seen solutions involving COM objects but I have to avoid using that because of portability issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter of `Method_Unknown_Size` is `double*` and you are changing the parameter *itself*. If you want to change the original value send by the caller, you should define the parameter as a *pointer to an array* which means *pointer to pointer of double* or *reference to pointer of double*

You should also in some way, tell the caller the size of the array (I guess you managed that already).

C++:

```
int method_Unknown_Size(double *&array)
{
    int size = 9;
    array = new double[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) array[i] = i;
    return size;
}

void FreeArray(double *&p)
{
    delete[] p;
    p = NULL;
}

extern "C" int __stdcall Run_Unknown_Size(cObject *pObject, double *&array)
{
     return cObject->Method_Unknown_Size(array);
}

extern "C" void __stdcall Release(cObject *cObject, double *&array)
{
     if(cObject != NULL) cObject->FreeArray(array);
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("cObject.dll")]
private static extern int Run_Unknown_Size(IntPtr pObject, 
       out IntPtr arr_not_allocated);

[DllImport("cObject.dll")]
private static extern int Release(IntPtr pObject,
       ref IntPtr arr_not_allocated);


// to allocate the array:
IntPtr pArr;
int res2 = Run_Unknown_size(m_pNativeObject, out pArr);

// to free the array:
Release(m_pNativeObject, ref pArr);
```

This absolutely works! Tell me if it didn't!

Comment: thank you very much for a quick reply. I have this code on my work machine so tomorrow I'll definitely check it out. I've tried double pointer, but in slightly different way. I hope this would work! Just a quick question: in C# part you put attributes '[Out] out'. What doe sit mean?

Comment: You're welcome. I guess `[Out]` is not required here, but I put it for certainty. It tells the marshaller to put back the changes to the variable, but it only works for contents of objects and arrays. If the object *itself* changes, the `[Out]` will not help! Here is where `out` parameter modifier is used for. It cuases the parameter to be passes as a *reference* (or *pointer*). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) for more information.

Comment: It is very interesting. This is my first project involving managed/unmanaged code and you definitely opened my eyes to some things, which are not easy to find on the web or in textbooks. Thanks again!

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. But now I face different problem - I cant release the memory allocated for this array... It gives assertion error. Can you help please

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very very much. Now it's working as it should work, and, what is more important, your solutions are very precise, clear and make perfect sense! I'm very grateful for you time and help!

Comment: @user2028058 Thanks :-) I'm glad you're happy with the answer.